# how to select an element from json array and display on html

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

My DynamoDb local database schemas has below following items.

```
  {"Items": [{ "id": "A004","name": "ACC LR2","userId": ["1","2","3","4"], {"id": "0001","name": "ABG IT","userId": [ "8","9","10","11"]}}]}
```

i want to slect only userID and list it to my html page using nodejs. what do i do?

```
///// MY entire code
router.get('/groups/group-info', function(req, res, next) {
///////////////////////////////////////
console.log("id "+req.query.id);
    var params = {
    TableName: 'userGroup',      
};


console.log("PARAMS: "+JSON.stringify(params));
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else { 
       // console.log("These are Groups: "+ console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Items)));
         console.log("User DETAILS: "+ console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Items) ));
         // for each
function getUserId(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result.push(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

function getUserIdAll(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result = result.concat(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log( getUserId(data) );
console.log( getUserIdAll(data) );
         // for each end 

     res.render('group-info',{_userD : data.Items});
  }
}); 
/////////////////////////////////

/*  res.render('group-info', { title: '' });*/
});
//////Entire code end
```

THIS is how my entire code goes , what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "Items": [
        { 
            "id": "A004"
            , "name": "ACC LR2"
            , "userId": ["1","2","3","4"]
        }, { 
            "id": "0001"
            , "name": "ABG IT"
            , "userId": ["8","9","10","11"]
        }
    ]
}

function getUserId(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result.push(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

function getUserIdAll(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result = result.concat(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log( getUserId(data) );
console.log( getUserIdAll(data) );
```

### Update 1:

```
function getUserId(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result.push(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

function getUserIdAll(obj){
    result = []
    obj.Items.forEach( function(item, i){
        result = result.concat(item.userId);
    });
    return result;
}

///// MY entire code
router.get('/groups/group-info', function(req, res, next) {
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    console.log("id "+req.query.id);
        var params = {
        TableName: 'userGroup',      
    };


    console.log("PARAMS: "+JSON.stringify(params));

    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("User DETAILS: "+ console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Items) ));
            res.render('group-info',{_userD : getUserIdAll(data) });
        }
    }); 
/////////////////////////////////

/*  res.render('group-info', { title: '' });*/
});
```

Comment: Hey i have edited my above code and pasted what you have done... could you please check and see what am i doing wrong ?? and what do I do?

Comment: Done. I moved 2 function from request callback. All other looks normal. I never used dynamodb and don't know is there all correct. Check documentation, please, if you have some errors. Or it works as expected?

Comment: it's a just a generic recommendation - a good answer shouldn't be code only but also explain what you did and maybe why - make it easier to anyone else coming on SO to benefit from it. Make it easy for myself and other users to upvote it if it deserves it!

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm write.... Mmm... "self-commented" code. My code = my words. Mo more, no less. If code bad - it need long and complicated explanations. If good - it no need explanations. I'm programmer and my code - is my words. Something like this =)

Comment: sure will do , what i am trying to do is , in my DynamoDB i have more than 20 entries like { "id": "A004","name": "ACC LR2","userId": ["1","2","3","4"]

Comment: And you want to collect "userId" from all entries?

Comment: hi VoidVolker , please go through link which has  detailed info about the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678695/how-to-select-an-element-from-json-array-and-display-on-html-using-nodejs  .. Help is appreciated